# continuity of map between to two spaces with the dictionary order topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm suppose to show the following map is continuous, which i thought I had but then I ran into a counterexample.

Given $\phi : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, where both the domain and range is given the dictionary order topology. $\phi$ is define by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.

If I consider the preimage of an element such as $U = (-a \times -b,a \times b )$, then in my mind $\phi^{-1}(U) = (-a \times -b, -a \times -b ) = \emptyset$.

According to munkres(theorem 18.1) if $\phi$ is continuous, that is equivalent to $\phi(\overline A) \subset \overline{\phi(A)}$, for any subset A of $\phi$'s domain. But then:

$\overline U = [-a \times -b, a \times b] \Rightarrow \phi(\overline U) = [-a \times -b, -a \times -b]$, ie a single point, while

$\overline{\phi(U)} = \overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset$, which contradicts the theorem in munkres.

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong with this line of thinking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The pre-image of 
$$
U = (-a\times -b, a \times b)$$
is 
$$
\phi^{-1}(U) = \left[ \bigcup_{b' < b} (-a \times b', -a \times b) \right]
\cup 
\left[ \bigcup_{-a<a'a''<a, b', b'' \in \Bbb{R}} (a \times b^\prime, -a \times b) \right]
\cup \left[ \bigcup_{b' > -b } (a \times b, -a \times b'') \right]
$$
That is, the pre-image is the strip between $-a$ and $a$, along with parts of the "vertical" lines at $-a$ and at $a$.  This is emphatically not the empty set.

That might be where you went wrong.